# C# EXT.NET: SetValue of textfield in RowExpander - Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Tags: c#, extjs, ext.net

I am trying to set the value of a `textfield` in a `rowexpander` in codebehind or in js on `AfterRender` event listener, but I get

> Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Here is the `textfield` in the `rowexpander`:

```
<ext:TextField runat="server" Name="notedown" FieldLabel="Note Under" ID="fnotedown">
   <Listeners>
          <AfterRender Handler="if (form.record.data.Lid != null && form.record.data.Lid != '' )
          {
             setNoteUnder_js(form.record.data.id);
          }" />

   </Listeners>
</ext:TextField>
```

JS:

```
var setNoteUnder_js = function (fieldid){
            #{DirectMethods}.setNoteUnder(fieldid,{
                success: function (result) {
                    #{fnotedown}.setValue(result); //undefined error
                }
            });
        }
```

Direct Method in Code Behind:

```
[DirectMethod]
public string setNoteUnder(int fieldid)
{
    DAL.CDMADataContext dc = new DAL.CDMADataContext();

    var field = (from f in dc.CFormFields
                 where f.cid == cid && f.id == fieldid
                 select f).FirstOrDefault();

    string units = null;

    if (field.Lid != null && field.Lid != "")
    {

         units = units + " Gender: " + field.text1 + " Unit: " + field.text2;

         fnotedown.SetValue(units); //undefined error

         return units;


    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That happen because you can't reference a text field by name inside a Row Expander, (several rows, several "notedown" fields ), i dont know if it works but try to pass your textfield as a parameter to the setNoteUnder_js function:   setNoteUnder_js(this, form.record.data.id);